# How to check whether Java plugins are installed or not in a browser using Code .?

Tags: java, javascript

How to check whether Java plugins are installed or not in a browser using java or javascript or JSP Code .?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java/Sun/Oracle provides [a deployment toolkit script](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) in the form of a JavaScript file that lets you achieve what you need.

You could invoke the `getJREs()` function which returns an array of currently-installed JRE version strings.

You can even install a particular JRE version if you need to, via the `installJRE(requestVersion)` function.

Comment: I used this one and it worked for me . thanks a lot Ryan and ysrb.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`deployJava.js`](http://java.com/js/deployJava.js)  to check the java installation.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
<META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
</HEAD>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" src="deployJava.js">
</SCRIPT>
<script type="text/javascript">
function call()
{
    if (deployJava.versionCheck("1.6.0+") || deployJava.versionCheck("1.4") || deployJava.versionCheck("1.5.0*")) 
    {
        alert("Java is Enabled");
    } else 
    {
        alert("Java is Not Enabled");
    }
}
</script>
<BODY onload="call();">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jqplugin

Eg.

```
jQuery.browser.java //Java
```

Comment: thanks.but do we have any code in java or Java script..? I dont want to use jQuery .?

Comment: JQuery is a javascript framework/library/helper. I really encourage you to use it. It really helps. You can configure it so that it will not conflict with other libraries.

Comment: I tried that  code but it returns "undefined" instead of true or false . Can u guide me on this please ..?

Comment: Can I see your HTML? Is it somewhere accessible? Do you have URL?

Comment: Older jquery version have problems detecting java plugin .use the script given below.

Answer (score 1):

I tried jqplugin and deployJava first, but those did fail for IE8 at least. So i came over this lib, that has the most comprehensive documentation and implementation that i could find and worked for all the browser that i could test

http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/Java/

Answer (score 1):

From [Navigator javaEnabled()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_nav_javaenabled.asp): `var x = "Java Enabled: " + navigator.javaEnabled();`

The result of x will be: Java Enabled: false